# Facebook Integration, iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook

Facebook is not integrating with my application. even the sample codes are not working
Is facebook having some problem with iOS because the documentation and sample codes on developer.facebook also not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Try this](https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API) new facebook grpah api

code for login on any button

```
fbGraph.accessToken = nil;
    NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (cookie in [storage cookies])
    {
        NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
        NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
        if(domainRange.length > 0)
        {
            [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
        }

    }




    [self loginButtonPressed:nil];
```

Comment: i also want to add a close button on facebook login. Please suggest

Comment: No, If user don't want to publish on facebook then after clicking the button on facebook popup it gets back to the application. same in facebook agent if you had seen.

Comment: means it is compulsory to login for come back in application

Comment: No once you login this api stores your username and password.If you put code  for logout and then leave application It will ask you login next time you start app

Answer (score 4):

use this [sharekit](http://getsharekit.com)

it can integrate facebook, twitter, and much more apis